# Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: validation, jsf, jpa, converters, selectonemenu

I have a problem with a p:selectOneMenu, no matter what I do I cannot get JSF to call the setter on the JPA entity. JSF validation fails with this message:

> form:location: Validation Error: Value is not valid

I have this working on several other class of the same type (ie, join table classes) but cannot for the life of me get this one working.

If anyone can throw some troubleshooting/debugging tips for this sort of problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Using log statements I have verified the following:

1. The `Conveter` is returning correct, non `null` values.
2. I have no Bean Validation in my JPA entities.
3. The setter `setLocation(Location location)` is never called.

This is the simplest example I can do and it simply will not work:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="location" value="#{locationStockList.selected.location}" converter="locationConverter">
            <p:ajax event="change" update=":form:lblLocation"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{locationStockList.locationSelection}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Location.class, value="locationConverter")
public class LocationConverter implements Converter, Serializable {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LocationConverter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value.isEmpty())
            return null;
        try {
            Long id = Long.parseLong(value);
            Location location = ((LocationManagedBean) context.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(context.getELContext(), null, "location")).find(id);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Converted {0} to {1}" , new Object[] {value, location});
            return location;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return new Location();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty() || !(value instanceof Location))
            return "";
        return String.valueOf(((Location) value).getId());
    }    
}
```

Console output:

```
// Getter method
INFO: Current value=ejb.locations.Location[id=null, name=null, latitude=0.0, longitude=0.0] 
// Session Bean
INFO: Finding ejb.locations.Location with id=3 
// Session Bean
INFO: ### Returning : ejb.locations.Location[id=3, name=mdmd, latitude=4.5, longitude=2.3] 
// Converter
SEVERE: Converted 3 to ejb.locations.Location[id=3, name=mdmd, latitude=4.5, longitude=2.3] 
// Getter method -> Where did my selected Location go ??
INFO: Current value=ejb.locations.Location[id=null, name=null, latitude=0.0, longitude=0.0]
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

> *Validation fails with the message "form:location: Validation Error: Value is not valid"*

This error boils down to that the selected item does not match any of the available select item values specified by any nested `<f:selectItem(s)>`  tag during processing of the form submit request.

As part of safeguard against tampered/hacked requests, JSF will reiterate over all available select item values and test if `selectedItem.equals(availableItem)`  returns `true` for at least one available item value. If no one item value matches, then you'll get exactly this validation error.

This process is under the covers basically as below, whereby `bean.getAvailableItems()` fictionally represents the entire list of available select items as defined by `<f:selectItem(s)>`:

```
String submittedValue = request.getParameter(component.getClientId());
Converter converter = component.getConverter();
Object selectedItem = (converter != null) ? converter.getAsObject(context, component, submittedValue) : submittedValue;

boolean valid = false;

for (Object availableItem : bean.getAvailableItems()) {
    if (selectedItem.equals(availableItem)) {
        valid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!valid) {
    throw new ValidatorException("Validation Error: Value is not valid");
}
```

So, based on the above logic, this problem can logically have at least the following causes:

1. The selected item is missing in the list of available items.
2. The `equals()` method of the class representing the selected item is missing or broken.
3. If a custom `Converter` is involved, then it has returned the wrong object in `getAsObject()`. Perhaps it's even `null`.

To solve it:

1. Ensure that exactly the same list is been preserved during the subsequent request, particularly in case of multiple cascading menus. Making the bean `@ViewScoped` instead of `@RequestScoped` should fix it in most cases. Also make sure that you don't perform the business logic in the getter method of `<f:selectItem(s)>`, but instead in `@PostConstruct` or an action event (listener) method. If you're relying on specific request parameters, then you'd need to explicitly store them in the `@ViewScoped` bean, or to re-pass them on subsequent requests by e.g. `<f:param>`. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885)
2. Ensure that the `equals()` method is implemented right. This is already done right on standard Java types such as `java.lang.String`, `java.lang.Number`, etc, but not necessarily on custom objects/beans/entites. See also [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract#3181374). In case you're already using `String`, make sure that the request character encoding is configured right. If it contains special characters and JSF is configured to render the output as UTF-8 but interpret the input as e.g. ISO-8859-1, then it will fail. See also a.o. [Unicode input retrieved via PrimeFaces input components become corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9634230).
3. Debug/log the actions of your custom `Converter` and fix it accordingly. For guidelines, see also [Conversion Error setting value for 'null Converter'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4734580) In case you're using `java.util.Date` as available items with `<f:convertDateTime>`, make sure that you don't forget the full time part in the pattern. See also ["Validation Error: Value is not valid" error from f:datetimeConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5406700).

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)
- [How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970)
- [Make multiple dependent / cascading selectOneMenu dropdown lists in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378099/make-multiple-dependent-cascading-selectonemenu-dropdown-lists-in-jsf)

---

> *If anyone can throw some troubleshooting/debugging tips for this sort of problem it would be greatly appreciated.*

Just ask a clear and concrete question here. Do not ask too broad questions ;)

Comment: @BalusC: Where exactly is it in the mojarra code, that this `equals` check happen. My situation is a bit complex. I create my own custom component that allow the user to have complex radio layout. It works fine if I just have one radio group (f:selectItems right underneath my custom component). However as the layout get more complex (multiple radio group, each have their own f:selectItems but all share the same selection), I have to have f:selectItems inside ui:repeat, then the ui:repeat is under my custom component. I then ran into this issue. I want to see the mojarra code that handle this

Comment: Also my f:selectItems is String type, so I am sure this is not a conversion problem, I think this is cause because the list of f:selectItems is not there during validation phase.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use f:param to send state to the managed bean so that it can recreate the "initial state"??? Thanks.

Comment: Having a similar error. I'm using the [SelectItemsConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) and this component is inside a disabled fieldset - so it is disabled as well. Is it a known behavior?

Comment: If you are using enum for the items to display and your backing bean have String type for setting the value in the bean and not using any converters you will get the same error. That is how I ended up here.

Comment: If i want to use my controller as @RequestScoped, what can i do to reinitialize it? I tried to load the items in the @PostConstruct method, but i got the `value is not valid` error.

Comment: Could it be possible that this error happens if there are two selectItems with different values but same description(visible text)? It has happened to me, and when deleted from database one of them, error message does not show up again...

Comment: Only if its equals() is broken, which is already covered by the answer.

Comment: @BalusC, I have a field which is not required=true and it is a date field, i do have validation for this field at the server sided based on other field value( like if the field 1 value is Y then enter date and validate the date if they are correct at server side). but when i try to enter wrong values in the date field like 11/11 and submit then it validates and gives error message. so how do i stop validation for one particular field all the time as i have validation for those field/all the field at server side. ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I forgot to implement a correct get/set methods. It happened because I have changed a lot of attributes along the development.

Without a proper get method, JSF can´t recover your selected item, and happens what BalusC said at item 1 of his answer:

> 1 .   The selected item is missing in the list of available items. This can happen if the list of available items is served by a request scoped bean which is not properly reinitialized on subsequent request, or is incorrectly doing the business job inside a getter method which causes it to return a different list in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a Converter Issue or else DTO issue. 
Try to solve this, by adding hashCode() and equals() methods in your object DTO; In the above scenario you can generate these methods within the Location object class which indicate as the 'DTO' here.

Example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Location other = (Location) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

- **Please note that the above example is for an 'id' of type 'long'.**

Comment: Like stated in #2 in the accepted and highly upvoted answer