# How to convert date in SelectOneMenu label to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: date, jsf, primefaces, label, selectonemenu

i have select a `SelectOneMenu` in my jsf page but display date like

> Thu May 30 00:00:00 WET 2013

but i want display it like 30/06/2013 in the jsf page. thats my code in my jsf page:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="Dateplanif" value="#{ gestionduplanning.dateplanificationnew}"> 
      <f:selectItems value="#{gestionduplanning.datelist}" var="da" itemValue="#{da}" itemLabel="#{da}"  />  
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

i am showing i list of date in jsf that the user need to chose one of them but i want to sow it like dd/MM/yyyy .

this a part of my managed bean :

```
List<Date> datelist = new ArrayList<Date>();
Date dateplanificationnew ;

public void initialize() {
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
     datelist = manageOfPlanifie.retournerdatedesplanif();
      }
```

how i can display it like dd/MM/yyyy ??

update 1 :

i used the solution of @mekk work but i cant validate and get the value of date after thats what i got
[image]

how to solve that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution to my problem with converting my date to String then back it to Date . i will show you a sample example of it :

this is my managed bean:

```
public class Testbean {
    @EJB
    private ManageOfPlanifieLocal manageOfPlanifie;
    List<Date> listdate = new ArrayList<Date>();
    List<String> listdatestring = new ArrayList<String>();
    String newdate="";
    Date dateplanification;     
 @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        listdate=manageOfPlanifie.retournerdatedesplanif();
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");     
        for(int i=0;i<listdate.size();i++)
        {listdatestring.add(formatter.format(listdate.get(i)));}     
    }  
    public String gototest2(String datedate) throws ParseException  
    {dateplanification= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(datedate);
        return "test2.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

test1.xhtml (my first jsf page)

```
<h2>Choix de l'equipe</h2>  
         <h:outputLabel for="dateplanif" value="date de planification : " />
         <p:selectOneMenu id="dateplanif"  value="#{testbean.newdate}" >             
             <f:selectItems value="#{testbean.listdatestring}" var="da" itemValue="#{da}" itemLabel="#{da}" />  
    </p:selectOneMenu>           

      <p:commandButton value="suivant"  style="color:black;" action="#{testbean.gototest2(testbean.newdate)}" update="@form" />
```

test2.xhtml

```
 <h:outputText value="Date : "/>   
 <h:outputText value="#{testbean.dateplanification}" />
```

this solution is working very well for me and escape problem in selectOneMenu .

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the item labels of `<h:selectOneMenu>`. The `<f:convertDateTime>` is not applicable as it applies to the item **value** only, not to the item **label**. The label is in your case just presented using the default [`Date#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) pattern which is indeed in format `Thu May 30 00:00:00 WET 2013` as described in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

Your best bet is *either* creating a `List<SelectItem>` instead of `List<Date>` wherein you convert the item labels yourself,

```
List<Date> availableDates = ...;
List<SelectItem> selectItems = ...;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

for (Date availableDate : availableDates) {
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem(availableDate, sdf.format(availableDate)));
}
```

*or* using `<f:selectItems var>` with an EL function in the `itemValue`. For example, the [OmniFaces `of:formatDate()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) (or [homegrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) one).

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableDates}" var="date" 
    itemValue="#{date}" itemLabel="#{of:formatDate(date, 'yyyy/MM/dd')}" />
```

This problem is by the way not specific to `<p:selectOneMenu>`, you would have exactly the same problem when using the standard `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Please note that you still need `<f:convertDateTime>` for the item values, otherwise you may end up in `Validation Error: Value is not valid` error because of time differences: [JSF 2 - f:selectItems with a Date keyed Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046309/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-a-date-keyed-map).

Comment: do you have an example with out Omnifaces ??

Comment: Just click the "homegrow" link?

Comment: I did not get the last part where do you need to put "f:convertDateTime" ? maybe in the p:selectOneMenu ? It seems it would be more simple to use a custom converter.

Comment: @Lucke: just click the link to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this:

```
convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd"
```

after your `selectItems` . I'm not sure if this works on your case but it terms of date, aside from creating EL function conversion, Im using this one.

Comment: This applies to item value only, not to item label.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{test.dates}" itemValue="#{currentDate}" var="currentDate"  itemLabel="#test.formatDate(currentDate)}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and   define formatDate() as

```
public static String formatDate(Date currentDate) {
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");   
     return dateFormat.format(currentDate);
}
```

Comment: i need now to fixe a new error that i have i made new post then i will continue to see with converstio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964863/selectonemenu-showen-red-when-have-date-value

Answer (score 1):

Use [OmniFaces `#{of:formatDate()}`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) function. It will work like a charm. And OmniFaces can combine with PrimeFaces or ADF.

Below is sample code in my application.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{periodId}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{appmsg['global.please_choose']}" itemValue=""/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{listPeriod}" var="p" itemValue="#{p.id}"
       itemLabel="#{of:formatDate(p.startDate, 'dd MMMM yyyy')" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you change the date pattern at the backing bean, before populating it in the `<p:selectOneMenu>`? That would be easier.

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItems value="#{test.dates}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And the Bean like this:

```
private List<String> dates;

public List<String> getDates() {
    return dates;
}

public void setDates(List<String> dates) {
    this.dates = dates;
}
public Test() {
    dates = dateList();
}
public List<String> dateList(){

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Date date1 = new Date();
    Date date2 = new Date(2013, 01, 01);
    list.add(dateFormat.format(date1));
    list.add(dateFormat.format(date2));
    return list;
}
```

See if this helps.

Comment: see my update. how i can change the date pattern for my datalist ??

Comment: but when the user chose a date i will have get String  in the bean but i need to get date.

Comment: Parse the String into a date object in the Bean.

Comment: @marouanoviche: you should read the basics first, then write codes.Roam through examples,read API.

Comment: Changing the data type of the value is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use omnifaces. There are sample following link.
http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates

Comment: i need solution with primefaces and jsf

Comment: @marouanoviche omnifaces is just a utility framework. it will work like a charm with primefaces.

Comment: so how i can solve my problem with omnifaces can you explain ?