# selectonemenu showen red when have date value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a sample selectOneMenu that have List of date and date as values but when i try to validate i have it red i will show you my sample example :

my managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Testbean {
    @EJB
    private ManageOfPlanifieLocal manageOfPlanifie;
        List<Date> listdate = new ArrayList<Date>();
        Date newdate;

 @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {     
        listdate=manageOfPlanifie.retournerdatedesplanif();;
    }
    public String gototest2(Date date)
    {

    return "test2.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    public List<Date> getListdate() {
        return listdate;
    }
    public void setListdate(List<Date> listdate) {
        this.listdate = listdate;
    }

    public Date getNewdate() {
        return newdate;
    }

    public void setNewdate(Date newdate) {
        this.newdate = newdate;
    }  
}
```

and this is my two jsf pages :

test1.xhtml

```
     <h:outputLabel for="dateplanif" value="date de planification : " />
     <p:selectOneMenu id="dateplanif" value="#{ testbean.newdate}">   
         <f:selectItems value="#{testbean.listdate}" var="da" itemValue="#{da}" />  
</p:selectOneMenu>        

  <p:commandButton value="suivant"  style="color:black;" action="#{testbean.gototest2(testbean.listdate)}" update="@form" />
```

test2.xhtml

```
  <h2>Choix de l'equipe</h2>  
     <h:outputText value="Date : "/>   
             <h:outputText value="#{ testbean.newdate}"/>
```

the problem i do sample transfer of data with out converstion just simple and i get that :

[image]

do you know i have it red and i cant move to the next page ??

Comment: when i remove value="#{ testbean.newdate}" from the SelecOnemenu it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a list of Objects, you need to convert them, so that setting the value works properly. Try the following code.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="dateplanif" value="#{testbean.newdate}">   
     <f:selectItems value="#{testbean.listdate}" var="da" itemValue="#{da}" />
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```