# Convert Date on SelectManyCheckbox Selection

Tags: jsf, date, primefaces, converters

i have a simple problem but i didnot find a solution for it.
I have a simple `p:selectCheckboxMenu` and i want use the selectedDates after click on the button.

I tried it with `f:convertDateTime`

```
<h:form id="mainform">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Date" value="#{myBean.selectedDates}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.dates}" var="date" itemValue="#{date}" itemLabel="#{myBean.convertDate(date)}"/>
                <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="Test" actionListener="#{myBean.printDates}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

but than i get an Error- Message: "Invaild Value".

Than i tried a Converter:

```
@FacesConverter("myDateConverter")
public class MyDateConverter extends DateTimeConverter{

public MyDateConverter(){
    setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
}}
```

and

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Date" value="#{myBean.selectedDates}" converter="myDateConverter">
```

But same error message. When i use no converter i get "String"- Values in my Date-List because type erasure.

**Question: How i get the selected dates as dates?**

Here is my bean for completeness:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

private List<Date> dates;

private List<Date> selectedDates;

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("POST CONSTRUCT!");
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
    dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    dates.add(new Date());
}

/**
 * 
 */
public void printDates(){
    for(Date d : selectedDates){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param date
 * @return
 */
public String convertDate(Date date){
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: Try removing `itemValue` and `itemLabel` from `f:selectItems`.

Comment: I have the same effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter is the source of the problem as it removes the time and then it uses the default time when converting back to Date.

You can use

< f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z" />

or try with a < f:datetimeconverter >

Comment: Thanks :) ... i found a link at the morning, too. Now it works :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046309/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-a-date-keyed-map