# Date Items in rich:pickList

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I make use of the RichFaces component *rich:pickList* to provide a list of Date objects which can be selected

When the data gets validated the JSF page shows a validation error: "Validation Error: Value is not valid". I know, the Date Object is somehow not converted. But I don't know why? 
First I tried setting the attribute dateConverter:

```
converter="#{javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter}"
```

This didn't work. Afterwards, I added the following statement:

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

Didn't solve the issue either.

Btw: What is the difference of both ?

Please find below the whole source code:

**XHTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:form prependId="false">
                <rich:pickList id = "datePL" 
                               value="#{richBean.listOfNewDates}"  
                               sourceCaption="All Dates" 
                               targetCaption="New Dates" 
                               >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{richBean.listOfDates}"
                                   var="_item" itemValue="#{_item}" itemLabel="#{_item}" />
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />

                </rich:pickList>

                <a4j:commandButton action="#{richBean.printListOfDates()}" value="Print"/>

                <rich:notifyMessages stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true" />

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

**Managed Bean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("richBean")
@SessionScoped
public class RichBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2403138958014741653L;
    private List<Date> listOfDates;
    private List<Date> listOfNewDates;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setListOfDates(new ArrayList<Date>());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        getListOfDates().add(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        getListOfDates().add(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
        getListOfDates().add(cal.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * @return the listOfDates
     */
    public List<Date> getListOfDates() {
        return listOfDates;
    }

    /**
     * @return the listOfNewDates
     */
    public List<Date> getListOfNewDates() {
        return listOfNewDates;
    }

    /**
     * @param listOfNewDates the listOfNewDates to set
     */
    public void setListOfNewDates(List<Date> listOfNewDates) {
        this.listOfNewDates = listOfNewDates;
    }

    public void printListOfDates() {
        for (Iterator<Date> it = listOfNewDates.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println("Neues Datum = " + it.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param listOfDates the listOfDates to set
     */
    public void setListOfDates(List<Date> listOfDates) {
        this.listOfDates = listOfDates;
    }
}
```

No exception is thrown on server side.

Could somebody help, please ? This would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this topic is adressed already several times but I can't find an answer to my issue. Any help is appreciated ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another post:[JSF 2 - f:selectItems with a Date keyed Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046309/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-a-date-keyed-map)

Don't know why I didn't find this post beforehand..