# Set radio-button item value with specific date

Tags: date, jsf, radio-button

I need to create four radio-buttons each of which should represent a specific date-interval. For instance, here is the piece of markup and the bean:

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
public class MyBean{
    Date dateFrom;

    //GET, SET
}
```

Markup piece:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.dateFrom}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="What?" itemLabel="#{msgs['bundleWithTodayLable']}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="What?" itemLabel="#{msgs['bundleWithLastWeekLabel']}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="What?" itemLabel="#{msgs['bundleWithLastYearLable']}"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I need to initialize the `dateFrom` property with the begin of today date, begin of the current week and begin of the current year. Is it possible to avoid `Java`-style `String` to `Date` conversions and do it strictly in JSF.

I'm using `JSF 1.2` in the porjcet I need to implement that feature.

Comment: Why is using a converter not JSF?

Comment: @Kukeltje Couldn't you show me how?

Comment: Cheock [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046309/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-a-date-keyed-map) and [here](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html?m=1)