# Problems with selectOneMenu j_idt31 Validation Error: Value is not valid

Tags: validation, jsf

I use SelectOneMenu, first i choose location, next building in this location then zone in building and subZone in this zone. First two select are good but when i take building choose there is no zones to show and i have error: j_idt31:selectedBld: Validation Error: Value is not valid. I don't know why;/

this is xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" position="center top">
        <h:outputLabel for="selectedLoca" value="#{loc['location']}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{caretakerCautionBean.location}" id="selectedLoca" converter="#{locationConverter}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{caretakerCautionBean.locationList}" var="loca" itemLabel="#{loca.name}" itemValue="#{loca}"/>
            <p:ajax update="selectedBld :messages" event="change" process="selectedLoca" listener="#{caretakerCautionBean.locationChanged}" /> 
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="selectedBld" value="#{loc['building']}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{caretakerCautionBean.building}" id="selectedBld" converter="#{buildingConverter}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{caretakerCautionBean.buildingList}" var="bld" itemLabel="#{bld.name}" itemValue="#{bld}" />
            <p:ajax update="selectedZone :messages" event="change" process="selectedLoca selectedBld" listener="#{caretakerCautionBean.buildingChanged}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="selectedZone" value="#{loc['zone']}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{caretakerCautionBean.zone}" id="selectedZone" converter="#{zoneConverter}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{caretakerCautionBean.zoneList}" var="zone" itemLabel="#{zone.name}" itemValue="#{zone}" />
            <p:ajax update="selectedSubZone :messages" event="change" process="selectedLoca selectedBld selectedZone" listener="#{caretakerCautionBean.zoneChanged}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <h:outputLabel for="selectedSubZone" value="#{loc['cleaningPlanner.tableHeader.subzone']}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{caretakerCautionBean.subZone}" id="selectedSubZone" converter="#{subZoneConverter}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{caretakerCautionBean.subZoneList}" var="subZone" itemLabel="#{subZone.name}" itemValue="#{subZone}" />
            <p:ajax update=":messages" event="change" process="selectedLoca selectedBld selectedZone selectedSubZone" listener="#{caretakerCautionBean.subZoneChanged}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton process="@form" value="#{loc['addComment']}" actionListener="#{caretakerCautionBean.addNewPosition()}" update=":messages" oncomplete="caretakerCautionsDialog.hide()"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class CaretakerCautionBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{caretakerCautionRepository}")
    private CaretakerCautionRepository caretakerCautionRepo;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{locationRepository}")
    private LocationRepository locationRepo;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{buildingRepository}")
    private BuildingRepository buildingRepo;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{zoneRepository}")
    private ZoneRepository zoneRepo;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{subZoneRepository}")
    private SubZoneRepository subZoneRepo;
    @ManagedProperty (value="#{userRepository}")
    private UserRepository userRepo;
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{userService}")
    private UserService userSvc;

    private List<CaretakerCaution> caretakerCautionList;
    private List<Location> locationList;
    private List<User> userList;
    private List<SubZone> subZoneList;
    private List<Building> buildingList;
    private List<Zone> zoneList;
    private Location location; 
    private SubZone subZone;
    private Building building;
    private Zone zone;
    private User user;
    private String description;
    private String comment;
    private String actionsTaken;
    private int id;

    private transient Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("aplikacjaLogger");

    public void locationChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
        if(location !=null)
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "locationChanged: "+location.getName());
        buildingList = null;
        getBuildingList();
    }

    public void buildingChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
        if(building != null)
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "buildingChanged: "+building.getName());
        zoneList = null;
        getZoneList();
    }

    public void zoneChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
        if(zone != null)
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "zoneChanged: "+zone.getName());
        subZoneList = null;
    getSubZoneList();
    }

    public void subZoneChanged(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) {
        if(subZone != null)
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "subZoneChanged: "+subZone.getName());
    }

    public void addNewPosition() {
        CaretakerCaution cc = new CaretakerCaution();
        cc.setLocation(location);
        cc.setBuilding(building);
        cc.setZone(zone);
        cc.setSubZone(subZone);
        getCaretakerCautionRepo().save(cc);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Dodano uwage.");
    }

    public BuildingRepository getBuildingRepo() {
        return buildingRepo;
    }

    public void setBuildingRepo(BuildingRepository buildingRepo) {
        this.buildingRepo = buildingRepo;
    }

    public ZoneRepository getZoneRepo() {
        return zoneRepo;
    }

    public void setZoneRepo(ZoneRepository zoneRepo) {
        this.zoneRepo = zoneRepo;
    }

    public UserRepository getUserRepo() {
        return userRepo;
    }

    public void setUserRepo(UserRepository userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public Building getBuilding() {
        return building;
    }

    public void setBuilding(Building building) {
        this.building = building;
    }

    public Zone getZone() {
        return zone;
    }

    public void setZone(Zone zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocationList() {
        if(locationList == null)
            locationList = getUserSvc().getLoggedIn().getCaretakenLocations();
        return locationList;    
    }

    public void setLocationList(List<Location> locationList) {
        this.locationList = locationList;
    }

    public List<CaretakerCaution> getCaretakerCautionList() {
        return caretakerCautionList;
    }

    public void setCaretakerCautionList(List<CaretakerCaution> caretakerCautionList) {
        this.caretakerCautionList = caretakerCautionList;
    }

    public SubZoneRepository getSubZoneRepo() {
        return subZoneRepo;
    }

    public void setSubZoneRepo(SubZoneRepository subZoneRepo) {
        this.subZoneRepo = subZoneRepo;
    }

    public List<SubZone> getSubZoneList() {
        if(subZoneList == null && zone != null)
            subZoneList = getSubZoneRepo().findByZone(zone);
        return subZoneList;
    }

    public void setSubZoneList(List<SubZone> subZoneList) {
        this.subZoneList = subZoneList;
    }

    public SubZone getSubZone() {
        return subZone;
    }

    public void setSubZone(SubZone subZone) {
        this.subZone = subZone;
    }

    public LocationRepository getLocationRepo() {
        return locationRepo;
    }

    public void setLocationRepo(LocationRepository locationRepo) {
        this.locationRepo = locationRepo;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public List<Building> getBuildingList() {
        if(buildingList == null && location != null)
            buildingList = getBuildingRepo().findByLocation(location);
        return buildingList;
    }

    public void setBuildingList(List<Building> buildingList) {
        this.buildingList = buildingList;
    }

    public List<Zone> getZoneList() {
        if(zoneList == null && building != null)
            zoneList = getZoneRepo().findByBuilding(building);
        return zoneList;
    }

    public void setZoneList(List<Zone> zoneList) {
        this.zoneList = zoneList;
    }

    public CaretakerCautionRepository getCaretakerCautionRepo() {
        return caretakerCautionRepo;
    }

    public void setCaretakerCautionRepo(
        CaretakerCautionRepository caretakerCautionRepo) {
        this.caretakerCautionRepo = caretakerCautionRepo;
    }

    public UserService getUserSvc() {
        return userSvc;
    }

    public void setUserSvc(UserService userSvc) {
        this.userSvc = userSvc;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getActionsTaken() {
        return actionsTaken;
    }

    public void setActionsTaken(String actionsTaken) {
        this.actionsTaken = actionsTaken;
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uiComp, String stringVal) {
    if(stringVal == null || stringVal.trim().equals("")) return null;
    else {
        Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(stringVal);
        for(Zone zon: this.getZonRepo().findAll()) 
            if(zon.getId() == userId) {
                return zon;
            }   
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uiComp, Object obj) {
    if(obj == null || obj.equals("")) {
        return "";
    } else {
        try {
            return String.valueOf(((Zone)obj).getId());
        } catch(ClassCastException cce) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

public ZoneRepository getZonRepo() {
    return zonRepo;
}

public void setZonRepo(ZoneRepository zonRepo) {
    this.zonRepo = zonRepo;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation Error: Value is not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069660/157882)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the bean scope, so by default it is `RequestScoped`. Currently you are doing AJAX requests without `execute=""` attibutes, the default is @this so the bean is recreated only with part of the data.

In your case you need to keep values between actions so you will need to use `ViewScoped` or `SessionScoped`.

I suggest you to use `ViewScoped` like this :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CaretakerCautionBean {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: By default it won't be `@RequestScoped` but `@NoneScoped`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm _Scope annotations set the scope into which the managed bean will be placed. If scope is not specified then bean will default to request scope. Each scope is briefly discussed below_

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza With this example you can even test it : http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=126