# Validation Error: value is not vaild

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

This error is happening sometimes. It's not always that happens, and so I am not able to find solution. The error happens when I select an item from the list (I repeat, the error only happens SOMETIMES). 
I've implemented the methods 'equals' and 'hashCode' and created the converter.
See the code below:

```
                 <p:outputLabel for="pais" value="País:" />
                 <p:selectOneMenu id="pais" value="#{clienteController.pais}" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{clienteController.paises}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.nome}" itemValue="#{p}"/>                     
                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{clienteController.actionCarregaUfs}" update="uf" />
                 </p:selectOneMenu>









package control;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import dao.PaisDao;
import dao.PaisDaoImp;

import model.Pais;

@FacesConverter(forClass=Pais.class)
public class PaisConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String value) {      
    if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
        PaisDao paisDao = new PaisDaoImp();
        return paisDao.findById(Integer.valueOf(value));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object value) {
    if (value instanceof Pais) {
        Pais pais = (Pais) value;   
        return String.valueOf(pais.getCodigo());
    }
    return "";
}



}












package control;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import dao.ClienteDao;
import dao.ClienteDaoImp;
import dao.PaisDaoImp;
import dao.TipoDocumentoDaoImp;
import dao.UnidadeFederacaoDaoImp;

import model.Cliente;
import model.Municipio;
import model.Pais;
import model.TipoDocumento;
import model.UnidadeFederacao;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ClienteController implements Serializable {

private Cliente cliente;
private DataModel listaClientes;
private List<Cliente> filteredClientes;
private Boolean isInsercao;
private Boolean isAlteracao;

private Pais pais;
private List<Pais> paises;
private List<UnidadeFederacao> ufs; 
private UnidadeFederacao uf;
private List<Municipio> municipios;

private List<TipoDocumento> tiposDocumentos;

public ClienteController() {
    this.cliente = new Cliente();
    this.pais = new Pais();
    this.ufs = new ArrayList<UnidadeFederacao>();
    this.uf = new UnidadeFederacao();
    this.municipios = new ArrayList<Municipio>();
    this.tiposDocumentos  = new ArrayList<TipoDocumento>();
}

public List<Cliente> getFilteredClientes() {
    return filteredClientes;
}

public void setFilteredClientes(List<Cliente> filteredClientes) {
    this.filteredClientes = filteredClientes;
}

public DataModel getListarClientes() {
    List<Cliente> lista = new ClienteDaoImp().list();
    listaClientes = new ListDataModel(lista);
    return listaClientes;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public String prepararAdicionarCliente() {
    cliente = new Cliente();
    isInsercao = true;
    isAlteracao = false;                
    return "gerenciarCliente";
}

public String prepararAlterarCliente() {
    isInsercao = false;
    isAlteracao = true;
    this.pais = this.cliente.getMunicipio().getUf().getPais();
    this.uf = this.cliente.getMunicipio().getUf();
    return "gerenciarCliente";
}

public String excluirCliente() {
    Cliente clienteTemp = (Cliente) (listaClientes.getRowData());
    ClienteDao dao = new ClienteDaoImp();
    dao.remove(clienteTemp);
    return "index";
}

public String actExcluirCliente() {
    ClienteDao dao = new ClienteDaoImp();
    dao.remove(cliente);
    return "index";
}   

public String adicionarCliente() {
    System.out.println("Adicionando Cliente...");
    ClienteDao dao = new ClienteDaoImp();
    dao.save(cliente);
    return "index";
}

public String alterarCliente() {
    ClienteDao dao = new ClienteDaoImp();
    dao.update(cliente);
    return "index";
}

public Boolean getIsInsercao() {
    return isInsercao;
}

public void setIsInsercao(Boolean insercao) {
    this.isInsercao = insercao;
}

public Boolean getIsAlteracao() {
    return isAlteracao;
}

public void setIsAlteracao(Boolean alteracao) {
    this.isAlteracao = alteracao;
}


/**************************************************/


public Pais getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(Pais pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

public List<Pais> getPaises() {
    paises = new PaisDaoImp().list();
    return paises;
}

public void setPaises(List<Pais> paises) {
    this.paises = paises;
}

public List<UnidadeFederacao> getUfs() {
    return ufs;
}

public void setUfs(List<UnidadeFederacao> ufs) {
    this.ufs = ufs;
}

public UnidadeFederacao getUf() {
    return uf;
}

public void setUf(UnidadeFederacao uf) {
    this.uf = uf;
}

public List<Municipio> getMunicipios() {
    return municipios;
}

public void setMunicipios(List<Municipio> municipios) {
    this.municipios = municipios;
}

public List<UnidadeFederacao> getUfsByPais() {                          
    ufs = new PaisDaoImp().getUFsByPais(this.pais.getCodigo());
    return ufs;
}   

public void actionCarregaUfs() {
    ufs.clear();
    if (this.pais != null) {
        if (!String.valueOf(this.pais.getCodigo()).equals("")) {
            this.getUfsByPais();            
        }
    }                                       
}

public List<Municipio> getMunicipiossByUf() {                           
    municipios = new UnidadeFederacaoDaoImp().getMunicipiosByUF(this.uf.getCodigo());
    return municipios;
}   

public void actionCarregaMunicipios() {
    municipios.clear();
    try {
        this.uf.getCodigo();
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        return;
    }       
    this.getMunicipiossByUf();
}       

public List<TipoDocumento> getTiposDocumentos() {
    tiposDocumentos = new TipoDocumentoDaoImp().list();
    return tiposDocumentos;
}   

}









package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "pais")
public class Pais implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id_pais")
private Integer codigo;
@Column(length = 4)
private String sigla;
private String nome;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais")
private List<UnidadeFederacao> unidadesFederacao;

public Pais() {
}

public Object getId() {
    return nome;
}

public Integer getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getSigla() {
    return sigla;
}

public void setSigla(String sigla) {
    this.sigla = sigla;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public List<UnidadeFederacao> getUnidadesFederacao() {
    return unidadesFederacao;
}

public void setUnidadesFederacao(List<UnidadeFederacao> unidadesFederacao) {
    this.unidadesFederacao = unidadesFederacao;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Pais))
        return false;
    Pais other = (Pais) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (other.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}   

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Validation Error: Value is not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9069660/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation Error: Value is not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid)