# h:outputText to conditionally render groups of JSF elements no longer working in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, rendered-attribute

I have some code that uses `<h:outputText>` to conditionally render groups of JSF elements. Examples:

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{authorization.admin}">
  <h:outputText value="#{msgs.someinfo}" />
  <h:inputSecret value="#{usermanager.password}" />
</h:outputText>
```

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{contactmanager.editAction}">
  <li>
     <label for="name"><h:outputText value="#{msgs.nameinfo}" /></label>
     <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contactmanager.name}" />
     <h:messages for="name" />
  </li>
</h:outputText>
```

The code is on glassfish 2.1.1 which has the MANIFEST.MF in jsf-impl.jar looking like this (I'm not sure whether it actually uses this jar or some other one for JSF):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_19-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Specification-Title: JavaServer Faces
Specification-Version: 1.2MR2
Implementation-Title: Mojarra
Implementation-Version: 1.2_13-b01-FCS
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sun
Extension-Name: com.sun.faces
```

I'm trying to move to glassfish 4 which has some version of JSF 2 or higher.

All the hundreds of instances of this construct worked on the old glassfish, but they no longer work on the new one - they are replaced with nothing, regardless of what the `rendered` attribute evaluates to. Why?

Comment: AFAIK you should not use `<h:outputText>` to wrap the content you want to render or not. Use `<ui:fragment>` instead. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3713468/1065197 for more options.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: But the construct seems to be uncontested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17685804/which-properties-in-a-jsf-backing-bean-can-be-set-by-a-user)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: `<h:outputText>` was used the same way there, and nobody said not to do it.

Comment: Then looks like `#{authorization.admin}` always returns `false` (similar with other beans). There's not enough info to reproduce the problem. I would recommend creating a new page and try to isolate it to find the real culprit. By the way, GlassFish 4 uses JSF 2.2 by default.

Comment: That's a weird way of doing things...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: "they are replaced with nothing, regardless of what the rendered attribute evaluates to.". In other words, replacing it with rendered="true" doesn't even work.

Comment: Again, *there's not enough info to reproduce the problem*. Did you try to isolate the problem or just keep complaining against an incomplete figure of the problem? I already made a test with `rendered="true"` and works with no problem, so your real problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, since JSF 2.0, children of `UIInput` and `UIOutput` are by default not anymore rendered. This is the consequence of fixes for [issue 1154](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1154). In Mojarra 2.x, you can still turn it back on via a `web.xml` context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
    <param-name>true</param-name>
</context-param>
```

See also the [Mojarra 2.0.0 release notes](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.0/whatsnew.html).

It's however more recommended to instead use `<h:panelGroup>` or `<ui:fragment>` for conditional rendering of blocks as the `<h:outputText>` is just the Wrong Tool™ for the job.

Comment: I couldn't use `<h:panelGroup>` because it creates a `<div>` or `<span>` in the HTML, which changes the web browser's behavior. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf) post is saying `<ui:fragment>` doesn't support the `rendered` attribute? So far I've started converting the `<h:outputText>`s to `<c:if>` and it's working.

Comment: The `<h:panelGroup>` does **not** create a `<div>` or `<span>` as long as you don't specify attributes which should end up in client side. As to the `<ui:fragment>`, it certainly supports the `rendered` attribute, please re-read that post. It's simply a documentation bug, not a logic bug.