# JSF2 ValueExpression in h:outputText does not evaluate to true despite same expression does in primefaces p:cellEditor

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I defined a value expression in 2 tags.
While both are defined as expecting a javax.el.ValueExpression,

```
<p:cellEditor rendered="#{!row.labelMode.toString().isEmpty()}">
```

works fine, while

```
<h:outputText value="#{msgs.pg_fieldMsg}"
              rendered="#{!row.labelMode.toString().isEmpty()}"/>
```

always renders, obviously ignoring the rendered attribute or evaluating it wrongly or different.

LabelMode is an enum (kotlin).
Same is when I replace toString() by name().
This behaviour is independent from server (Jetty ot Tomcat)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to
[h:outputText to conditionally render groups of JSF elements no longer working in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868898/houtputtext-to-conditionally-render-groups-of-jsf-elements-no-longer-working-in)
outputText is the "Wrong Tool™ for the job".

Despite that, the javadoc for outputText still names the render method as operative :-/