# how to use same List instance variable of backing bean for h:selectOneListbox and h:selectManyListbox

Tags: jsf-2, converters, managed-bean

I have a requirement to use same variable of a request scoped backing bean which is a List datatype for h:selectOneListbox and h:selectManyListbox. I get "ip: Validation Error: Value is not valid" error with h:selectOneListbox  even after using a converter. Can some one help me resolving this ?

In page1.xhtml I've given it as:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="ip" value="#{inputBean.ipAddress}" size="5">
<f:selectItems value="#{inputBean.ipAddressList}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

In page2.xhtml I've given it as:

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="ip" value="#{inputBean.ipAddress}" size="5">
    <f:selectItems value="#{inputBean.ipAddressList}" />
    <f:converter converterId="ipAddressConverter"></f:converter>
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

My Input bean, a request scoped managed bean looks like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class InputTablePlot implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@ManagedProperty("#{database}")
private Database database;
private Connection connection;
    private StringBuilder query;
    private PreparedStatement pst_query;
    private ResultSet rs;

private List<Long> ipAddress;
private Map<String, Long> ipAddrMenu;

public InputBean()
    {
        ipAddrMenu = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>();
    }
@PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
ipAddrMenu.clear();
try
        {
            connection = database.getDbConnection();
            query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("SELECT distinct source AS ipaddr FROM addrtable ORDER BY source");
            pst_query = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString());
            rs = pst_query.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                ipAddrMenu.put(ipLongToString(rs.getLong("ipaddr")), rs.getLong("ipaddr")); // Adding
                // sources
            }
            rs.close();
            pst_query.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
       public List<Long> getIpAddress()
    {
        System.out.println("In Getter" + ipAddress);
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(List<Long> ipAddress)
    {
        System.out.println("In Setter");
        System.out.println(ipAddress);
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;

    }
        public Map<String, Long> getIpAddressList()
    {
        return ipAddrMenu;
    }

    public void setIpAddressList(Map<String, Long> ipAddressList)
    {
        this.ipAddrMenu = ipAddressList;
    }

@Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
result = prime * result + ((connection == null) ? 0 : connection.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((database == null) ? 0 : database.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((ipAddrMenu == null) ? 0 : ipAddrMenu.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((ipAddress == null) ? 0 : ipAddress.hashCode());
return result;
}

@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        InputBean other = (InputBean) obj;
if (connection == null)
        {
            if (other.connection != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!connection.equals(other.connection))
            return false;
        if (database == null)
        {
            if (other.database != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!m_database.equals(other.database))
            return false;
        if (ipAddrMenu == null)
        {
            if (other.ipAddrMenu != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!ipAddrMenu.equals(other.ipAddrMenu))
            return false;
        if (ipAddress == null)
        {
            if (other.ipAddress != null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (!ipAddress.equals(other.ipAddress))
            return false;

return true;
}

}
```

Converter code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;


public class IpAddressConverter implements Converter
{

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2)
    {
        List<Long> ipAddr = new ArrayList<Long>();
        try{
            ipAddr.add(Long.valueOf(arg2)); 
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Problem with conversion of ip!");
            facesContext.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        }
        for(int i=0; i< ipAddr.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("ipAddr >>> "+ipAddr);   
        }
        return ipAddr;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
    {
        String val = null;
        try{
        Long ip = (Long) arg2;
        val = ip.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Problem with conversion of ip!");
            facesContext.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        }
        System.out.println("value >>> "+val);
        return val;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It failed because `List<Long>` as returned by the converter doesn't match the individual `Long` item of the available items while JSF is validating the submitted (and converted!) value against the list of available items (as part of safeguard against tampered/spoofed HTTP requests wherein attacker manipulated the selected item value). The converter is supposed to return a `Long`. All with all, such a converter is simply insuitable for usage in an `UISelectOne` component.

You'd better bind the value straight to a single property. If you insist in using a `List` property, then just prepare it with a single empty item and specify the list item index in the value.

```
private List<Long> ipAddress = new ArrayList<>(1);
```

with

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="ip" value="#{inputBean.ipAddress[0]}" size="5">
    <f:selectItems value="#{inputBean.ipAddressList}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

#### See also:

- [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660)

Comment: Thanks for replying, You mean to say I use a Long instance variable for h:selectOneListbox and List<Long> for h:selectManyListbox ditching converter? I looked into the link you posted, my getter for ipAddress variable returns null.

Comment: The `<h:selectOneListbox>` must as being an `UISelectOne` component be bound to a `T` property, not to a `T[]` or `List<T>` property like as with an `UISelectMany` component like `<h:selectManyListbox>`. Your concrete problem is caused because `Long != List<Long>`. Your converter was incorrectly returning `List<Long>` instead of `Long`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I changed my h:selectOneListbox to h:selectManyListbox and modified my logic to run for multiple ip addresses.