# INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed

Tags: jsf, message

I created an user interface with a form to get information from user. When I submit the form, it prints the following warning in the server log:

```
INFO: WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=j_idt7:j_idt11[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt7:j_idt11: Validation Error: Value is not valid), detail=(j_idt7:j_idt11: Validation Error: Value is not valid)]
```

I tried to solve it, however I didn't understand how. How is this problem caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As to the warning referring an undisplayed `Validation Error: Value is not valid` message, this means that you've somewhere a `<h:selectXxx>` component such as `<h:selectOneMenu>` without an associated `<h:message>` and therefore JSF is not able to display faces messages about conversion/validation errors directly in the UI.

In order to fix the particular warning, just add a `<h:message>`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="foo" ... />
<h:message for="foo" />
```

Note that when you're ajax-submitting the form using `<f:ajax>`, then you should not forgot to include the messages in the ajax-update. To start with, use `render="@form"` to update the entire form.

As to the concrete validation error problem which is mentioned in the message, head to the following answer: [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660).

Comment: But i used <h:message../>
`<h:inputText value="#{restaurant.name}"
   required="true"
               requiredMessage="Error"
               id="name"/>
    <h:message for="name" styleClass="error"/>`

Comment: You need to define it for **all** input components, also the `<h:selectXxx>` components. The validation error "Value is not valid" mentioned in the message is typical for a `<h:selectXxx>` component.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add `<h:message>` in a `<h:selectOneMenu>`

Comment: That's already shown in the answer. It's not different from how you add it to (not in!!) the `<h:inputText>`.

Comment: I added `<h:messages globalOnly="true">` at top of the page, but still showing the warning (Wildfly log) and no error message is shown in the page

Answer (score 0):

If you are using primefaces, dont forget to add:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
        ....
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Not specifically needed. `h:mesage`, `h:messages` or the p counterparts works as well as long a you follow common jsf guidelines

Comment: Well, indeed Led Machine said "if you're using Primefaces". Depending by the case, `p:growl` can be more appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

It is invalid value problem. Most probably you entered character instead of integer value. Check this and I suggest exception handling to not face these type of problems again.