# Where does "Validation Error: Value is not valid" come from

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF form and a managed bean. Upon submission of my form one of the inputs returns

sendMessage:template: Validation Error: Value is not valid

I believe these are the names of the form and input. However I have no validation at all on the field either in the JSF page or on the bean. How is this possible?

here is the field in question:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="template" value="#{sendMessageController.template}">  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{sendMessageController.availableTemplates}"  />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

and the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="sendMessageController")
@RequestScoped
public class SendMessageController {
    ....
    private String template;
    private List<String> availableTemplates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: Which type has the value in the bean? Maybe there is some conversion necessary which fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This validation error is recognizable from `UISelectOne`/`UISelectMany` components where `<f:selectItem(s)>` are being used, such as `<h:selectOneMenu>`. This validation error will occur when the selected value has not returned `true` on the `equals()` check with any of the available items.

This has in turn three possible causes:

1. The `equals()` method of the select item value is missing or broken.
2. The list of available items has incompatibly changed between displaying and submitting the form.
3. If any involved, the `Converter` has returned the wrong item or even `null` in `getAsObject()`.

#### See also:

- [Our `<h:selectOneMenu>` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)
- [Validation Error: Value is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/)

Comment: I think my problem is 2. I have two other inputs which are used to calculate what is available in the selectOne

Comment: Then just make sure that it doesn't incompatibly change. E.g. put the bean in view scope, or recreate the same list in (post)constructor of the request scoped bean. If some additional parameters are required for this, just pass them along.

Comment: Debugging it appears the problem is that after submit the postconstruct is called, and at that point the values for the other fields used to get availableTemplates are null (even though they have been populated in the page by the user) so Im unable to reset availableTemplates. I do not understand why this is, as I'd already made a call to a web service to get those values, I'd prefer to avoid doing it again.

Comment: It's because your bean is **request** scoped. Every HTTP request creates  logically a new bean instance. Displaying the form counts as one HTTP request. Each ajax request counts as one HTTP request. Submitting the form counts as one HTTP request. That's just how HTTP works. Again, as advised, put bean in view scope to keep the instance alive as long as you're interacting with the same form. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/

Comment: doh. Of course. It was supposed to be session scoped.