# SelectItem's values

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, selectoneradio

When traversing the source code for `UISelectOne`, I came across the following piece of code within the `protected void validateValue(FacesContext context, Object value)` method:

```
boolean found = SelectUtils.matchValue(getFacesContext(),
                                               this,
                                               value,
                                               new SelectItemsIterator(context, this),
                                               getConverter());
```

Consider the following declaration:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.pr}" converter="Conv" required="true" requiredMessage="msg">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.dates}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

The converted value should be equal to one of the values I've populated the list with. The actual value has a different type than expected, so I get a validation error.

**Question:** Why is the converted value not consistent with the validated value?

Comment: This is covered by http://stackoverflow.com/q/9069379 (safeguard against manipulated/tampered/hacked requests). Is this acceptable as dupe?

Comment: @BalusC I just wanted to know the reasond for the `SelectUtils.matchValue` method performing the searching through the `SelectItem`s. Now the reason is clear (safeguard). So yes, it is.