# Primefaces Validation error with converter and equals working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters

I got a problem with **p:selectOneMenu** of PrimeFaces in JSF. I read a lot of questions asked about the same problem but nothing helped me.

When I set up my component the same way I used to do wherever in my project, if I try to select one of items of my **selectOneMenu**, this error appears :

> Validation Error: Value is not valid

Lot of people resolve this by correcting the **Converter** class or **equals()** methods, but nothing look wrong in mines.

**Converter**

```java
@RequestScoped
public class BaremeConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private BaremeBean baremeBean;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                return baremeBean.loadById(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((Bareme) object).getId());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

**BaremeBean** is the entityBean of this class which is loading data fine. My workspace is full of converters like this so except if i miss something in this one, it should work here.

**equals() method of class Bareme**

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof Bareme)) {
        return false;
    }
    Bareme other = (Bareme) object;
    return !((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)));
}
```

This is the equals() method generates by Netbeans and nothing looks wrong here too.

Finally, I give you the code of the component I use, and same thing as previous ones, the same code works for others classes I got.

```html
<h:outputLabel for="forfaitBareme" value="Barème" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="forfaitBareme" class="print-w100p-lab" value="#{transportFacturationBean.forfait.bareme}" converter="#{baremeConverter}" >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{transportFacturationBean.baremesForfait}" var="b" itemLabel="#{b.id}" itemValue="#{b}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":centralPanel" process="@form" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**transportFacturationBean.baremesForfait** is a java.util.List which contains few Bareme.

You should know that the code below is working well using another custom object of my project. **Camion** is implemented the same way as **Bareme**, their converters are similar, and their equals() method are both the ones generated by Netbeans.

```html
<h:outputLabel for="forfaitCamion" value="Camion" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="forfaitCamion" class="print-w100p-lab" value="#{transportFacturationBean.forfait.camion}" converter="#{camionConverter}" >  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{transportFacturationBean.camions}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.type}" itemValue="#{c}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update=":centralPanel" process="@form" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: The duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/9069379 describes a third cause which you left unmentioned.

Comment: @BalusC If you're talking about the selected item could be not in the available ones, my item is firstly null and as you can see i added the f:selectItem with value null which work for my Camion object. I also tried to select another item in my list of available ones in my ManagedBean but the error is still here.

Comment: Uh, I wasn't talking about null items. Just that the item which was selected is not anymore in list of available items at the moment when the form submit is actually processed.

Comment: Sure, maybe I'm expressing myself badly but i checked this. I display my list of available items in the same form as my component and this list still contains each element I am able to select in my oneMenu when the error fires (knowing that my change event update this display).

Comment: "BaremeBean is the entityBean" - no, looks like BaremeBean is EJB, and Bareme could be a JPA entity bean. In which case its equals method is wrong, because it refers to the `other.id` field directly, so it risks seeing an empty proxy field. It should instead go through a getter: `other.getId()`.

Comment: A wrong equals method could be the root of the problem, since selectOne checks that one of the avalaible options was in fact selected.

Comment: My equals method is never call and this one is working fine when i check it manually. BaremeBean is my entityBean while Bareme is my pure Entity. equals don't look to be the problem here.

Comment: In Stackoverflow it is not needed to edit titles when things are solved. Accepted answers are the indication of things being solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED ! The **biggest smallest** mistake I could imagine !

```
return baremeBean.loadById(Integer.parseInt(value));
```

My **loadById** method were returning a list instead of a simple object.... Sorry guys !