# Primefaces actionListener not being called when applied with FacesConverter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on a form that sends the selected values of a `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` to a `List<>` in a bean and calls a method that performs some logic on those selected items. The method was being called normally, but I was facing some issues with the values being processed into the list (I wished to pass some model objects, but what came were Strings of a property of that model).

I then implemented a `FacesConverter` to receive the id property and then retrieve the object from a DAO.
The converter worked without issues itself, but the method to perform logic was no longer being called. I noticed that by just removing the converter="myConverter" from the `<p:selectManyCheckbox>` the method would then be called again.
I'm not sure how to look further into this...

Here's the code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup id="contentDefault" layout="block">

<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{backBean.selectedList}"
    columns="1" layout="grid" converter="myConverter">

    <f:selectItems value="#{backBean.selectionList}"
        var="file" itemLabel="#{file.name}" itemValue="#{file}" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
                
<p:panelGrid id="bottomDefault" layout="grid" columns="1"
    columnClasses="text_center">

    <p:commandButton value="Download" icon="pi pi-download"
                process="contentDefault" partialSubmit="true"
        actionListener="#{backBean.downloadFiles()}">
        <p:confirm type="popup" header="Confirm"
            message="Download the files?"
            icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" />
    </p:commandButton>

</p:panelGrid>

</h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

Back bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "backBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BackBean implements Serializable {

private List<ModelObj> selectionList;
private List<ModelObj> selectedList;

private ModelObjDAO modelObjDAO;

public void downloadFiles() {
    for (ModelObj file : selectedList) {
        file.getNome();
    }
}

public List<ModelObj> getSelectionList() {
    return selectionList;
}

public void setSelectionList(List<ModelObj> selectionList) {
    this.selectionList = selectionList;
}

public List<Object> getSelectedList() {
    if (selectedList == null) {
        selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return selectedList;
}

public void setSelectedList(List<ModelObj> selectedList) {
    this.selectedList = selectedList;
}

}
```

Comment: Head to possible cause #3 of abovelinked duplicate. Provided that the converter is correct as you said yourself, then the chance is big you will now finally see a 'Validation error: value is not valid' message.

Comment: @BalusC No messages came up, but after I debugged it, I came across a code section in JSF that compared the selected values (the ones that returned from the converter) and the original values. Since the values came with some properties differing from a DAO, the comparison failed. I overran the `equals()` and now it works.

Comment: [It's indeed exactly this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid). Cause #3 namely explains how you can get validation/conversion messages to show up. Because your code in its current form indeed doesn't show any messages.